# Samba Unable to access drives other than root

Tags: samba4

Good Evening,

I am a relatively new Linux admin and have set up a file sharing network across our computers at home.  I am in the process of moving all things hosted to a box running Centos 7 from a Win10 box which will turn back into a normal workstation.  I still want to allow Win10 to put files to the Centos 7 server.  So, hello Samba 4.8.3.

As I'm learning Samba and how it works, I've been able to successfully setup and access an anonymous share provided it's on the root drive; however, the instant I attempt to move the directory location from the /samba/anonymous folder to a different drive, I cannot access it from the Windows box.

Here is what my smb.conf file looks like:

============================ Share Definitions ==============================

```
[anonymous]
comment = Anonymous File Server Share
path = /samba/anonymous
browsable = yes
writeable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
force user = wang

[Movies]
comment = Movies
path = /run/media/wang/Mobile_Wang/Movies
browsable =yes
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
force user = wang


[Shows]
comment = Shows
path = /run/media/wang/Big_Wang/Shows
browsable = yes
writable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
force user = wang
```

I verified the directories and they are good if I access them locally.  I also am running a Plex Media server and it can see all the directories.  Also, just to be redundant, the Anonymous share is accessible.

I suspect my issue is somewhere in how the drives are mounted, but being a newbie to Linux, I'm a little lost.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: What do the samba logs tell you? Are there any other relevant logs, e.g. `/var/log/messages` or `/var/log/secure` that have any information pertaining to this?

Answer (score 1):

It's most probably a permission thing.

Please compare `ls -ld /samba/anonymous` and `ls -ld /run/media/wang/Mobile_Wang/Movies`. Are group and permissions the same?
According to [Setting ACLs on the Shared Directories](https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Setting_up_Samba_as_a_Standalone_Server#Setting_ACLs_on_the_Shared_Directories) your anonymous folder should have permissions 2775 (rwxrwsr-x) with set group id set.

Even if the permissions are not set as described, then changing "Movies" to the same permissions as "anonymous" should make your movies share accessible. Run `chmod -R <perms>`/`chgrp -R <group>` if needed to change permissions recursively.

If your new shares are mounted ntfs partititions, then have a look at [How to share NTFS partition with Samba](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=871686&p=8174290#post8174290).